# Admin only to change/edit specific API key of a AEM component

Tags: permissions, aem

I have created a component that displays weather information from a third party source (openweathermap.org/api) using their free API. For this I have created a servlet and upload it to AEM via maven build. Component is working fine and fetching the details as required.

Because you are using an APIKey, your site should allow the key to be changed/updated without a code change and be activated immediately without restarting CQ.
- **Only admins should be able to do this, authors should not see or worry about a key**.

Reference link: [system/console permissions](http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2012-09-07/cq55-osgi-systemconsole-permissions/)

I have been through lot of forums but no help. I am sure we have to work in http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr - but which part and what changes to be made not sure. Also how to trigger the servlet with the changed API key.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configurable OSGI service. The API key will then be a property of that service which can be modified by the admins from the Felix console.

For creating OSGI services, you should use the Felix SCR annotations and process those during your maven build process to generate the appropriate deployment descriptors. Here is a simple example.

```
@Component(immediate=true, label="Weather Service", description="My weather service", metatype=true)
@Service(value=WeatherService.class)
public class WeatherServiceImpl implements WeatherService {

    @Override
    public String getWeatherInfo() {
        return null; // call the weather api here
    }
}
```

Use the `@Property` annotation to define your configurable property as below and assign it to in the activate method of the service which gets called when the service is activated on bundle install.

```
@Property(value="123456789")
static final String WEATHER_API_KEY = "weather.api.key";

private String weatherAPIKey;


@Activate
public void activate(final Map<String, Object> props) {
    this.weatherAPIKey = (String)props.get(WEATHER_API_KEY);
}
```

You should see your configurable service in the Felix console after this.

Coming to permissions, the authors should not have permission to the Felix console at all. Only admins should have access to that.